# React Typescript. Issues populating an array state with an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following object.

```
const data = [
    {
        key: '1',
        name: 'John Brown',
        date: 'Mon Oct 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
        address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '2',
        name: 'Joe Black',
        date: 'Mon Oct 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '3',
        name: 'Jim Green',
        date: 'Mon Oct 31 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
        address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
        key: '4',
        name: 'Jim Red',
        date: 'Mon Oct 31 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)',
        address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    },
];
```

And this state

```
const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState([]);
```

I'm trying to setup its data with an useEffect on component mount.

```
React.useEffect(() => {

        setUsersData(result => [...result, data[0]])
        props.setLoading(false);
    }, []);
```

> But im having an issue with the setUsersData
>
> Argument of type '(result: never[]) => { key: string; name: string;
> date: string; address: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type '(result: never[]) => { key:
> string; name: string; date: string; address: string; }[]' is not
> assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
> Type '{ key: string; name: string; date: string; address: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
> Type '{ key: string; name: string; date: string; address: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts

UPDATE:

This is what I have currently.

const data = .... is still the same

I changed the useState to

```
const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState<any[]>([]);
```

And I do this now

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        setUsersData(result => [...result, data[0]])
        props.setLoading(false);
    }, []);
```

But this way it only adds the elemtn 0 to my array, and Im trying to add all the elements contained in data

Comment: why don't you do `setUsersData([...userData, data[0]])`

Comment: @WilliamWang well yea i can do that ,but its the same  ````Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.````

Comment: can you attach your whold codebase?

Comment: since you are using typescript, try `const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState<any[]>([]);`

Comment: I am confused as to why you are setting state like this ```setUsersData(result => [...result, data[0]])```. What are you trying to add to the state?

Comment: @yudhiesh the whole content of data. If i do it as someone said above (Williams), it works but it only adds the element in the index specified. And i want to add all the elements. I will update my question

Comment: `const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState<any[]>(data);` you can set the entire data object as an initial value for the usersData

Comment: @WilliamWang I dont want to set it as an initial value. Since this is mock data, but I will have to fetch it from an api on useEffect later on

Comment: check my answer @mouchin777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you are using typescript, you should do the type definition or simply `any`

```
try const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState<any[]>([]);
```

2. 

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        setUsersData(result => [...result, ...data])
        props.setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState([]);
```

Issue here is that typescript infer type of `[]` as `never[]` which means empty array.
So to fix issue you have to specify type providing generic argument to `useState`:

```js
type Item = {
    key: string,
    name: string,
    date: string,
    address: string,
}

// It will work even without specifying type here 
const data: Item[] = {
  //
}

const [usersData, setUsersData] = React.useState<Item[]>([]);
```

Providing type for `useState` says to typescript that this array of `Item`'s event if it's empty for now.

Comment: And after this, how do I use, setUsersData ? , since this ```setUsersData(result => [...result, data])``` fails

Comment: `setUsersData(result => [...result, data[0]])` or `setUsersData(data)`  or `setUsersData(result => [...result, ...data])`